# parse info from log files and quering process table

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to check how many log files have been modified in the last 10 minutes and list them.  I also want to do it in incriminates of 30.  Output would be like this:

```
   Log files modified in the last 10 minutes: X 
   List of these files:
   /var/log/messages
   /var/log/lastlog
   /var/log/wtmpp
   /var/log/cron

   Log files modified in the last 30 minutes: x
   List of these files:
   ....
```

Further, I want to query the process table and get the following:

```
    Total # of processes:  X
    Number of active user processes by user:
    root: 98 (or however many)
    Apache: 65
    UserA: 33
    UserB: 23

    Top 5 processes using the most memory
    listing of processes
```

I think that I can get the # of log files with this command:

```
    find /var/log/ -name '*.log' -mmin 10
```

and count them with adding " | wc -l" to get the #

but I get errors when I try to do that.

Any suggestions on how to go about do this I would appreciate.

Comment: could you write the error message you get?

Comment: post your error also here. So any one can get idea about what is going wrong. without it no one able to help you. Also batter to fire command with `sudo` like `sudo find /var/log/ -name '*.log' -mmin 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that you should write -10 to mmin.

```
find /var/log/ -name '*.log' -mmin -10
```